# Encrypt settings in web.config without using aspnet_regiis

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, web-config, iis-7.5

I'd like to encrypt some connection strings in my Web.config file. This web application is built on a TFS build server and deployed to several environments for testing. I would like to avoid running `aspnet_regiis` on each server to encrypt the config.

Is there a way to encrypt parts of the config file without using `aspnet_regiis`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the -EnableRule:EncryptWebConfig flag with MSDeploy.exe to encrypt sections of the web.config.

```
msdeploy.exe –verb:sync –source:iisapp=”sourceTestSite” –dest:iisapp=”destinationTestSite” –EnableRule:EncryptWebConfig
```

Here is an additional blog posts with further options:

https://blog.richardszalay.com/2016/02/10/encrypting-arbitrary-configuration-sections-using-msdeploy/